# Get list of li's of clicked ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a list structure like the following, I want to take the the text of `<li>` tags when clicked on the 'cssmenu3' class `<ul>`s, but the code

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sadaf2605/74jYb/6/

The code I am trying:

```
$(".cssmenu2 li").click(function () {
    $("#hello").append("started");
    var optionTexts = [1, 2];
    $(this).children().each(function () {
        optionTexts.push($(this).text());
    });
    alert(optionTexts.length);
    optionTexts.each(

    function () {
        $("#hello").append(this);
    }

    );

});
```

```
<div style="float:left; background-color:yellow; width:1200px; height:200px;" id="hello"></div>
<div id="top_cssmenu" style="float:left;">
    <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul class="cssmenu1">
            <li data-url="news.html" class='active has-sub'><a>Bangladeshi</a>

                <ul class="cssmenu2">
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>

                        <ul class="cssmenu3">
                            <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                            <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html" class="has-sub"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>

                        <ul class="cssmenu3">
                            <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                            <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>

                        <ul class="cssmenu3">
                            <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                            <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html" class="has-sub"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='has-sub menu_news'><a href='#'>West Bengal</a>

                <ul class="cssmenu2">
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>

                        <ul class="cssmenu3">
                            <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                            <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html" class="has-sub"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>

                        <ul class="cssmenu3">
                            <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                            <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>

                        <ul class="cssmenu3">
                            <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                            <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='has-sub menu_news'><a href='#'>Other</a>

                <ul class="cssmenu2">
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>

                        <ul class="cssmenu3">
                            <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                            <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html" class="has-sub"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <ul class="cssmenu3">
                        <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                        </li>
                        <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
            <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>

                <ul class="cssmenu3">
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li data-url="gallery.html" class="has-sub menu_gallery"><a href='#'><span>Gallery</span></a>

                <ul class="cssmenu2">
                    <li data-url="gallery.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>

                        <ul class="cssmenu3">
                            <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                            <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="gallery.html" class="has-sub"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>

                        <ul class="cssmenu3">
                            <li data-url="gallery.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                            <li data-url="gallery.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>

                        <ul class="cssmenu3">
                            <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                            <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist sub</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `.each` function for an array.

```
optionTexts.each
```

You could do

```
$.each(optionTexts, 
    function() { $("#hello").append(this); }

);
```

To use jQuery's `.each` function over the array

Comment: There is `.forEach`, though, which functions pretty much identically to jQuery's `.each`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand right but with this you'll get the text of `li`

```
$(".cssmenu2 li").click(function(){
        var text = $(this).children().html();
        $("#hello").append(text);
    });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74jYb/9/)